# Delete all files in a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, scripting

I have a directory which includes some files and some folders containing other files. I'm trying to remove these files in the main directory without touching the folders or their contents.

I'm using this

```
rm /media/d/data/*
```

it it working fine and only delete the files, but I wonder why the terminal displays this message:

`rm: cannot remove /media/d/data/dd1: Is a directory`

and same message appears for all the folders found under the main folder. Can anyone explain? and is there is a way not to display this message on terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This * picks up both **files** and **directories**. To delete files only try this

```
find /media/d/data/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete
```

Comment: Can't I use rm to do this?

Comment: You have a few options:
find /media/d/data/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -i rm {}
Or you can just use rm and get rid of the error messages:
rm /media/d/data/* 2>/dev/null

Answer (score 3):

By default, `rm` does not delete directories. If you want the directories to be removed, use `rm -rf`. If you want to suppress the message, use `rm <dir> 2>/dev/null`. Note that all other error message get suppressed, too.

Comment: I think `rm -r` would do..no need to use `-f`..

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly:

```
find ! -name . -prune -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

Comment: so where do I put my directory `/media/d/data/` in this command?

Comment: @shepherd: You need to `cd` to /media/d/data

Answer (score 1):

`rm` deletes the files you tell it to. `*` expands to all files (including directories), so you're telling `rm` to delete directories, which it won't do.

Most shells have no way to exclude directories from a wildcard pattern. Wildcard patterns only match files by name, not by type. You can [use `find` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189897).

Zsh has [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) which can match files by type, date, etc. **In zsh**, you can use

```
rm *(.)
```

to delete all regular files, or variants like `rm *(-.)` to delete regular files and symbolic link to regular files, `rm *(^/)` to delete all files except directories, etc.

Note also that `*` omits [dot files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) (files whose name begins with `.`). `find` will include them. In zsh, `*` omits dot files by default; you can add `D` inside the parentheses (e.g. `rm *(.D)`) to include them.